# Is there a way to duplicate a material node with it's keyframes?

Tags: node-editor, keyframes

I also tried by making a group of nodes and duplicating the group, but if I undo the groups, only one of them keeps the keyframes.

Comment: Which nodes are you writing about?

Comment: About material nodes

Comment: What do you mean by "with the keyframes"? That some value of a node is keyframed?

Comment: Yes! I keyframed some vales of the nodes